# Application installation failed in iPhone when installing in other iPhone

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, ios4, ios-simulator

im installing an application (which i have created) in to my iPhone and its getting installed, but when i try installing it in other iPhone then its showing "Installation failed",

I want to know where will be the problem..?

Comment: Is it registered in provisioning profile? If yes, are you using other iPhone first time to install your app?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not registered into developer.apple.com ?

Try add device to devices list

Answer (score 0):

Your device might not be registered. Select that device too in your devices which you have added while creating provisioning profile. You can  do this by clicking on 'Add new device' and entering that device's UDID.. try this...

Comment: If i will upload this application in app-store then can other people access this application?

Comment: offcourse you can.. You have to follow these steps ->1) make a valid provisioning of your app. 2) Add those devices on which you have tested or you may test your app before uploading it to app store. 3) For more confirmation about your app's perfection,make ipa of your app and test that ipa on your device. 4) After doing all above steps,you can upload your app to app store.

Comment: If you have some more doubts,feel free to ask me.. And if my answer has helped you,then do not forget to accept my answer and voting me up.

Comment: I want to know that, my app is working in my iPhone and not in other iPhone. If i upload this app in to app-store then whether it will work properly for those who download it?

Comment: No... if your app is not working on other iphone,then it will be rejected by app store.

Comment: then wer will be the problem? is it in distribution certificate or development certificate?

Comment: you have to make a distribution certificate before uploading your app to app store,haven't you made it yet?????

Comment: i have a distribution certificate but that is given by someone else.. will it work?

Comment: No, distribution certificate only for testers or App Store

Comment: can any one send me the screenshot of code signing page..? so that i can c to it and do the needy..

Comment: do we need both distribution certificate and development certificate?

Comment: how to generate and install them? how to setup in code-signing of xcode?

Comment: Visit [http://developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) ,select 'Certificates' and follow given steps.

Comment: The link is [this](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action).... you need to log in first.